# How to exit from the current session on Linux gracefully?

Tags: linux, shell

I need to exit from the current session and I am using the following code:

```
read -p "Do you want to start a new session? [Y/N] " usr_session
if [ "$usr_session" == "y" ] || [ "$usr_session" == "Y" ]; then
   echo -e "`date`\t\t Exiting...\n You will need to login back...\n" >> $LOG_FILE
   echo -e "Exiting...\n You will need to login back...\n"
   sleep 5
   curr_usr=`whoami`
   pkill -9 -u $curr_usr
elif [ "$usr_session" == "n" ] || [ "usr_session" == "N" ]; then
    echo -e "You are still in the same session.\n"
else
    echo "Invalid input"
fi
```

Is there a better approach to perform the same but in more graceful manner? I feel the killing the current user process might not be safe. Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is calling `exit` not a viable solution for some reason?

Comment: `exit` will terminate the current script, not the entire session.

Comment: Yes, exit is not exiting from the session.

Comment: What do you intend to use it for?

Comment: Rather than kill -9, you should consider using kill -2 for HUP.

Comment: Please define better what session you are talking about. What Linux distribution, what graphic environment, etc. Killing all the processes belonging to a user might be wrong, killing them with -9 is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Consider using `logout`.</strike>

(If you don't care to immediately terminate all running processes, including background jobs)

You could send a "softer" signal first instead of -9, to give time for the processes to shut down gracefully, then only send -9 to the processes that won't exit.

`logout` will work only if you are able to run this script as part of the login script (such as `bashrc`), not if it's run in a subshell. Alternatively (with the same effect), run the script with `exec script_name` from the login shell.

Another idea is to `kill -HUP $PPID`, assuming that the script is always run directly as a subshell of the login shell. This will signal the parent shell (the login shell) to end the session.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a wrapper script and then source in , for example

file : wrap1.sh

```
./myscript.sh 
if [ $? != 0 ];then
   exit
fi
```

replace kill with exit 1 and from main session :

```
source wrap1.sh
```